# PluginError during publication error in parsing: Unexpected token =>

Tags: javascript, gulp

Im trying to make a publication of a webapp into a server(WindowsServer2012), Im using .NET Visual Studio 2019,
When I try to publish it this error pops:

```
[PluginError: Error in parsing: "Sensores\creadorGraficos.js", Line 14: Unexpected token =>] {
 showStack: false,
 showProperties: true,
 plugin: 'gulp-angular-filesort',
 __safety: { toString: [Function: bound ] }
 }
 Procesar terminados con el código 1.
```

last sentence translation:

> Process ended with code 1

The code is nothing fancy, just a .map :

```
var presionatmosferica = dataURL.map(function (elemF) {
            return elemF.map(o => { return { fecha: o.fecha, presionatmosferica: o.presionatmosferica } })

        });
```

so the problem is the token:

> =>

Any idea why this is happening?

By the way, the publication is being made by other PC, my guess was that Gulp was not installed so I run:

> npm install gulp

and still the same error.

Comment: Your environment doesn't support Arrow functions.

Comment: @ChrisG damit! Ok thanks for the answer, I guess gotta rewrite the code. Any alternative to the arrow function in this env?

Comment: Just use a regular function. Replace `o =>` with `function(o)`

Comment: Okey, thanks for your time man. Im learning on my own and its difficult af.